# Is there a way to use ngModel and NgFor together?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel, ngfor

I would like to reset the values of checkboxes when user clicks on button "cancel". Is there a way I could use ngFor and NgModel together so that the values would reset? I'm trying to set the object that `*ngFor` uses to an earlier version.

**HTML**

```
   <div *ngFor="let object of objects">
            <input [(ngModel)]="object.isSelected" type="checkbox"> 
   </div>

   <button type="button" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
```

**TypeScript**

```
cancel(){
   this.object = this.unChangedObject;
}
```

The values do reset, but how could I show the changes to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deep copy your object to another variable using `Object.assign` and assign it in the cancel function

```
constructor(){
  this.unChangedObject = Object.assign({},this.object  )
}

cancel(){
   this.object = this.unChangedObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at it the other way. To only update when commit. For this you could use a pipe on the `*ngFor` which returns an array of copied objects. This solution will only work with shallow objects though, but you can try to find some deep copy method as well (untested code below):

**pipe**

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'copyArr'
})
export class CopyArrPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(arr: object[] = []): object[] {
    return arr.map(obj => ({...obj}));
  }
}
```

**template**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="objects | copyArr as objectsCopy">

  <div *ngFor="let object of objectsCopy">
    <input [(ngModel)]="object.isSelected" type="checkbox"> 
  </div>

  <button type="button" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
  <button type="button" (click)="commit(objectsCopy)">Commit</button>
</ng-container>
```

**component**

```
@Component({...})
export class FooBarComponent {

  objects = [];

  cancel(){
    this.objects = [...this.objects];
  }

  commit(newObjects) {
    this.objects = newObjects;
  }
}
```